# Laravel Eloquent and Query Builder "with (nolock)"

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have some throuble because my queries not have `with (nolock)` instruction after `from` clause.

Because that, some queries **lock the database** and then nobody can use the system.

How to use `with (nolock)` with Eloquent & Query Builder?

For example.. in this query:

```
return static::with('campaignType')
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

I want the follow result:

```
select
    *
from campaigns with (nolock)
inner join campaign_types with (nolock) on campaign_types.id = campaigns.campaign_type_id 
where campaigns.active = 1
```

Comment: Please post some code for us to review. You may also want to look at DB::raw method if Laravel doesn't support what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `DB::raw` works, but I want a eloquent/query builder solution. Only if there is no option in eloquent, I try to use raw.

Comment: how do you solve this issue? I have same issue

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I deal it with eloquent (Tested on Laravel 5.1 and 5.2)

You need to add scope in your model:

```
public function scopeNoLock($query)
{
    return $query->from(DB::raw(self::getTable() . ' with (nolock)'));
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
return Model::noLock()->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set "with(nolock)" like this:

```
DB::table('campaigns')->lock('WITH(NOLOCK)')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Did not know that query builder had this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
/**
 * @param $query
 * @return $this
 */
public function scopeNoLock($query)
{
    return $query->from($query->getQuery()->raw(self::getTable() . ' with (nolock)'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use too a native solution with the method [sharedLock](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2062)